# is there a way to format a cell in such a way that after the first 2 numbers u get a semi colon and after that the 2 last numbers

Tags: excel, formatting

Below are the actual and to be expected cell number format. I used ##":"## but as soon as i type in 0020 it shows 0:20 and if i type in 0002 it shows 0:2

[actual and example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83elD.png)
[used number format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucpb8.png)

as descripted im expecting a 4 number input where in between the 4 numbers there comes a semi colon even if there are zero's

Comment: Try: `00\:00` but this should nt be used instead use `VBA` or `Excel Formulas` since cell formatting is facade. The underlying cell will still read as `0020` and you wont be able to use it for further time calculations. You would still need a formula to parse those actual times.

Comment: Found this online:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e#:~:text=Click%20File%20%3E%20Options.,Use%20system%20separators%20check%20box.

Answer (score 1):

What you see happens because leading zeros are normally dropped ("0002" is the same as "2"). If you want to explicitly pad with a certain number of zeros, you need to use "0" in the formatting code instead of "#".

So, try

```
"00:00"
```

If you always have a four-digit input, that should work as expected. N.B., the input will still be read and understood as a four-digit decimal number, but it will be displayed the way you want it.